# Yeoman Installing successfully after installation, it shows command not error

Tags: node.js, yeoman

I had installed yeoman succesfully, when i execute yo in cmd,it is showing below error.

[image: Yeoman Error]

i had cleared the cache of npm, i unistalled this and reinstalled yo but, no effects Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Iam answering this question, open enviroment variables, edit path and added the C:\Users\profile_name\AppData\Roaming\npm

Then everything is alright